# Spyder set Working Directory (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, spyder

I'm new to Spyder to do some python script and I have a problem with my working directory so that I can't use relative paths.

So in `Tools -> Preferences -> Run` I set: Default working directory is: `"The directory of the file being executed"`

However when I open `Spyder` and then open a `*.py-file`, I can't import a CSV in a sub directory due to `"File ... does not exist"`. I checked with `os.getcwd()` and it always shows my User-Directory. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the subfolder? I mean, if you have `.../script.py` and want to load `data.csv` that is located at `.../subfolder/data.csv`, then you would specify `subfolder/data.csv` as the path to open.

Comment: I did... finally I figured out that this error occurs, when I only run a part of my script via Strg+Enter. When I run the total script everything works fine... seems to be a bug I think.